# C# string - creating an unescaped backslash

Tags: c#, .net, string, escaping

I am using .NET (C#) code to write to a database that interfaces with a Perl application.  When a single quote appears in a string, I need to "escape" it.  IOW, the name `O'Bannon` should convert to `O\'Bannon` for the database UPDATE.  However, all efforts at string manipulation (e.g. .Replace) generate an escape character for the backslash and I end up with `O\\'Bannon`.

I know it is actually generating the second backslash, because I can read the resulting database field's value (i.e. it is not just the IDE debug value for the string).

How can I get just the single backslash in the output string?

R

Comment: "I need to "escape" it ... for the database UPDATE." <-- Shouldn't you be using *placeholders*?

Comment: Use the @ sign var RepName = @"O\'Bannon";

Answer (score 5):

Well I did

```
"O'Bannon".Replace("'","\\'")
```

and result is

```
"O\'Bannon"
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: When I put that in my immediates window in VS it is returning ""O\\'Bannon"

Comment: @MikeHanrahan The immediate window shows it in a valid literal form. Try these two expressions: `"\\"` and `"\\".Length`. Also, look at it in the Watch window, where it should be "raw". However, if you are using this to make it "safe" for SQL, something is *likely wrong* about the approach.

Comment: @MikeHanrahan: I did it LinqPAD using `Dump` or `Console.WriteLine()` in `C# Interactive` console gives the result as provided in answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `"\\"`, which is the escape char followed by a backslash.

See the list of Escape Sequences here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

even better assign a var to the replace  so that you can check it as well if needed

```
var RepName = "O'Bannon";
var Repstr = RepName.Replace("'","\\'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a verbatim string

```
s = s.Replace("'", @"\'");
```